# How does std::begin() work for builtin types?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have below lines of code where I am using std::begin .

```
int myint[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
std::find(begin(myint),end(myint),9);
```

Now std::begin is declared as below .

```
template< class C > 
auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

I am not able to understand , how does it work ?. AFAIK ,return type of std::begin is decltype(c.begin()) ,when C is passed as array of integers , there will not be any begin function with integers .So c.begin() should be invalid ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't. What you're missing is that there is another version of the begin/end pair that is chosen by the compiler for the built-in array, and it looks roughly like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T (&ar)[N]) {
  return ar;
}
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T (&ar)[N]) {
  return ar + N;
}
```

These functions give you pointers to the beginning and past the end of a normal array. The version that calls a member `c.begin()` is removed from the overload resolution by SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks very much .Do we have similar version of cbegin for arrays ?Using cbegin or cend on arrays will result into compilation error ..right? as there is no appropriate  cbegin for arrays .

Comment: There is; the global `cbegin` and `cend` simply forward to the global `begin` and `end` and then add `const`, so they should work with arrays. However, this is a C++14 addition, and your compiler might not yet support it.

Comment: Where can i check syntax for such addition? .Even http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin says , there is no special cbegin/cend for bulit in types .

Comment: You can grab drafts of the standard from here: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/

Comment: Thanks you very much @sebastian .You were of great help !

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL It should work well. I've tried a [sample](http://ideone.com/z5Z5xa) here.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Yes , it will work .My compiler was little older .Thanks for pointing it out .

Answer (score 2):

[std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) has other template overload version for build-in array.

> (since C++11)(until C++14)

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```

> (since C++14)

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
constexpr T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```